# Osmnx and basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, osmnx

Is it possible to have osmnx and basemap in the same environment? I've been trying to install it but had no luck. I need to plot some coordinates with basemap that I got from osmnx and connect them with lines. If anyone knows an alternative to basemap I would be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`basemap` was [deprecated](https://www.scivision.dev/cartopy-replace-deprecated-basemap/) a couple years ago and eventually replaced by `cartopy`, which I encourage you to use instead... `basemap` creates dependency conflicts since it is incompatible with recent releases of many packages.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that `cartopy` wasn't still fully operational and would replace `basemap` sometimes later this year

Comment: See also https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/920#issuecomment-321329691